# Comparar dos listas y mostrar en una tercera lista las intersecciones con Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo estas dos listas las cuales necesito comparar con Linq, estaba leyendo sobre intersection pero no lo comprendí muy bien espero me puedan ayudar:

```
List<string> NamesGroupA = new List<string>(){
            "Juan Robles",
            "Pedro Perez",
            "Jose Fernandez"
        };
        
List<string> NamesGroupB = new List<string>(){
            "Juan Robles",
            "Pedro Perez",
            "Raul Robles"
        };
```

Deseo poner los nombres que se repiten en una lista de esta manera:

```
List<string NamesRepet = new List<string>(){
     "Juan Robles",
     "Pedro Perez",
};
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el **método Intersect** de **Linq** el cual devuelve los elementos que hay en común entre conjuntos:

```
var listIntersect = NamesGroupA.Intersect(NamesGroupB).ToList();
```

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla de lograr esto puede ser usando el método [Where](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) combinado con el método [Contains](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.Contains?view=net-5.0).

> - Where: Filtra una secuencia de valores en función de un predicado
> - Contains: Determina si una secuencia contiene un elemento especificado.

```
IEnumerable<string> NamesRepet = NamesGroupA.Where(x => NamesGroupB.Contains(x));
```

Tomando en cuenta que la comparación por si sola retornará un `IEnumerable<string>`, pero si quieres directamente que retorne `List<string>` solo debes convertirlo a Lista, al final, asi:

```
List<string> NamesRepet = NamesGroupA.Where(x => NamesGroupB.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

> Como también en vez de usar el método Contains, puedes usar el método [Any](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0)

```
List<string> NamesRepet = NamesGroupA.Where(x =>  NamesGroupB.Any(y => y == x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias también me sirvio.