# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar en consola las cadenas de texto repetidas de dos array en C# - Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

Este es el código que estoy utilizando pero cuando recorro ambos array no reconoce ninguna repetición. Si bien en ambos array están los mismos nombres, al modificar el orden no reconoce tal repetición. ¿En qué puedo estar fallando?

```
[SerializeField]
string[] edificio1 = { "Mariana", "Carina", "María", "Melisa", "Yina", "Norma", "Nuri", "Yenny", "Carlos", "Linda", "Marcela", "Lorena" }; 

[SerializeField] 
string[] edificio2 = { "Carina", "Mariana", "Melisa", "María", "Norma", "Yina", "Yenny", "Nuri", "Linda", "Carlos", "Lorena", "Marcela" };

private void Start()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int c = 0;
   
    while (i < edificio1.Length && j < edificio2.Length)
    {
       if (edificio1[i] == edificio2[j])
        {
          c++;
        }

        j++;
        i++;
    }

    Debug.Log("Cantidad de nombres que coinciden en ambos arrays: " + c);
}
```

Comment: Entra aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/410485/comparar-dos-listas-y-y-mostrar-en-una-tercer-lista-las-intersecciones-con-linq/410502#410502

Comment: Claro que no lo reconoce puesto que el código lo planteaste para que funcione si están en orden. La forma de hacerlo sería recorriendo un arreglo y por cada ciclo recorrer el otro viendo si son iguales. En 2 arreglos de 3 elementos cada uno sería algo así: `a[0] == b[0], a[0] == b[1], a[0] == b[2], ...`

Comment: Muchas gracias, Mateo. Eres muy amable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien te dice @Mateo en los comentarios, lo que haces en tu código es:

- Mientras la variable "i" sea menor que el array 1
  y
  la variable "j" sea menor que el array 2

Comparar:

- Si la posición 0 del array 1 es igual a la posición 0 del array 2
- Si la posición 1 del array 1 es igual a la posición 1 del array 2
- Si la posición 2 del array 1 es igual a la posición 2 del array 2
- Si la posición 3 del array 1 es igual a la posición 3 del array 2
- ...

Evidentemente, haciendo esa comprobación, jamás tendrás dos nombres coincidentes en la misma posición

Lo que tienes que hacer es un bucle, podemos seguir con tu bucle while, que recorra el primer array, y un segundo bucle, en éste caso te puse un For, que secorra el segundo array

Lo que hace ahora, es:

- Si cualquier dato del array 2 coincide con la posición 0 del array 1, incrementa en 1 la variable c.
- Si cualquier dato del array 2 coincide con la posición 1 del array 1, incrementa en 1 la variable c.
- Si cualquier dato del array 2 coincide con la posición 2 del array 1, incrementa en 1 la variable c.
- Si cualquier dato del array 2 coincide con la posición 3 del array 1, incrementa en 1 la variable c.
- ...

finalmente se imprime el resultado de la variable c

```
string[] edificio1 = { "Mariana", "Carina", "María", "Melisa", "Yina", "Norma", "Nuri", "Yenny", "Carlos", "Linda", "Marcela", "Lorena" };

string[] edificio2 = { "Carina", "Mariana", "Melisa", "María", "Norma", "Yina", "Yenny", "Nuri", "Linda", "Carlos", "Lorena", "Marcela" };


        int i = 0;
        int c = 0;

        while (i < edificio1.Length)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < edificio2.Length; j++)
            { 
                if (edificio1[i] == edificio2[j])
                {
                    c++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Cantidad de nombres que coinciden en ambos arrays: " + c);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eres muy amable.